# Don't understand the meaning of this: n, S = map(int, input().split()) (In Dynamic Programming)

Tags: python, algorithm, variables, dynamic

I'm trying to learn Dynamic programming but there is some difficult lines of code that are hard to know. Idk what do we suppose to do with these lines of codes:

```
n, S = map(int, input().split())
w = list(map(int, input().split()))
dp = [0] * (S + 1)
dp[0] = 0
```

Comment: Please post the full code into the *question* (properly formatted).

Comment: dp = [0] * (S + 1) -> be careful while using * operator to create a list. 
Refer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/240178

Answer (score 4):

This has not much to do with dynamic programming itself.

```
n, S = map(int, input().split())
```

will query the user for input, and then split it into words, convert these words in integers, and unpack it into two variables `n` and `S`. This thus will succeed when the user enters two numbers (not more, not less).

It works as follows:

1. `input()` will query the user for input, and read one line of user input;
2. `.split()` will split that input into a list of "words";
3. `map(int, ...)` will call `int` on each word, it will to that lazily (although that is not important here); and
4. `n, S = ...` will unpack the expression into two elements, and assign the first one to `n` and the second one to `S`.

For example:

```
>>> n, S = map(int, input().split())
14 25
>>> n
14
>>> S
25
```

But it will error if you pass only one number, three numbers, etc. like:

```
>>> n, S = map(int, input().split())
14
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
>>> n, S = map(int, input().split())
14 25 37
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
>>> n, S = map(int, input().split())
foo bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'foo'
```

The line:

```
w = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

does more or less the same thing, but instead takes as input from the user a sequence of numbers. There can be zero, one or more numbers. `w` will store a list of numbers. The `list(..)` part forces Python to evaluate the `map(..)` eagerly.

```
dp = [0] * (S + 1)
```

Here we will construct a list with `S + 1` zeros. In Python, you can multiply a list (and tuple) with an integer *n*. The result is a list (or tuple) that is *n* times as large as the original list, and it repeats the elements. For example:

```
>>> [1,4,2,5] * 3
[1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 4, 2, 5]
```

Since here the given list contains *one* zero, it will thus produce a list that contains `S+1` zeros.

Finally

```
dp[0] = 0
```

will set the first element to zero. But since that was already the case, this line is not very useful.

Comment: thanks but the operator here is quite hard to understand is there any tips to learn these things ?

Comment: @QuânĐoàn: what operator?

Comment: Sorry, i mean the syntax here is a little complex. How can i get get used to with these things